# How to install virtual keyboard?

Tags: keyboard, touch-screen

I am running Arch Linux (KDE) on a laptop with a touchscreen. I would like to install a virtual (on-screen) keyboard. I would like to know the most basic steps for using the most common virtual keyboard. (I did not find a wiki page on Arch Linux for virtual keyboards.)

I tried installing [florence](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/florence/), but it remapped the keys in a way that seemed broken and it also prevented the physical keyboard from working correctly. I had to uninstall it to make my laptop usable again. None of the other virtual keyboards I tried would even come up.

Comment: You had no luck with anything via IBus?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean